# Implement FireBase Phone verification?

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, xcode8

Can anyone lead me through how to implement Firebase phone verification, I have followed this poor document with no luck:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

The official documentation of this service is so poor, can anyone provide working example or lead me how to.

Note:
I know how to implement Firebase to the project via cocoapods and I also import the Google-services Json file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    What errors are you getting? Did you check the Auth example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/authentication

Comment: FirebaseUI is the easiest way to get this working quickly: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS#firebaseui-for-ios--ui-bindings-for-firebase-

For an example of general Firebase Auth usage, you can check out the sample code from the Firebase iOS codelab: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/ios

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).